# R - how to get median and mean with string field?

Tags: r

I have a table (Class) like this:

```
County    Age.Group  
Albany      0-5  
Albany      10-15  
Albany      10-15  
new York    5-10  
new York    5-10  
new York    0-5  
LI          0-5  
LI          0-5  
LI          0-5
```

I need to get mean and median by County so I know I need to calculate the how many times Albany, New York, and LI appeared in the list and then use the mean and median function. I'm not sure how to do this as I get an error message when I use mean or median as that field is not an integer. Please help.....

Comment: What is your expected output for, say, Albany?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is your exact expected output if it is not the following, it should help you somewhat forward.

```
> # Load data
> df <- data.frame(County    = c("Albany", "Albany", "Albany", "new York",
+                                "new York", "new York", "LI", "LI", "LI"),
+                  Age.Group = c("0-5", "10-15", "10-15", "5-10", "5-10", "0-5",
+                                "0-5", "0-5", "0-5"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> 
> # Split the age by "-", resulting in a list
> age_split <- strsplit(df[, 2], split = "-", fixed = TRUE)
> 
> # Turn numeric and take middle point of group, sapply turns back into vector
> df$Age.Group.Mean <- sapply(age_split, function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
> 
> # Print df
> df
    County Age.Group Age.Group.Mean
1   Albany       0-5            2.5
2   Albany     10-15           12.5
3   Albany     10-15           12.5
4 new York      5-10            7.5
5 new York      5-10            7.5
6 new York       0-5            2.5
7       LI       0-5            2.5
8       LI       0-5            2.5
9       LI       0-5            2.5
> 
> # Calculate what is needed
> aggregate(Age.Group.Mean ~ County, data = df, median)
    County Age.Group.Mean
1   Albany           12.5
2       LI            2.5
3 new York            7.5
> aggregate(Age.Group.Mean ~ County, data = df, mean)
    County Age.Group.Mean
1   Albany       9.166667
2       LI       2.500000
3 new York       5.833333
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that @snoram's interpretation of your desired output is correct- if so, here is a `dplyr` alternative:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(County) %>%
    summarise(
        mean.age = mean(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(Age.Group, "-")))),
        median.age = median(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(Age.Group, "-"))))
    )

> data.frame(df2)
    County mean.age median.age
1   Albany 9.166667       10.0
2       LI 2.500000        2.5
3 new York 5.833333        5.0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(County = c("Albany", "Albany", "Albany", "new York", 
                                "new York", "new York", "LI", "LI", "LI"), Age.Group = c("0-5", 
                                                                                         "10-15", "10-15", "5-10", "5-10", "0-5", "0-5", "0-5", "0-5")), .Names = c("County", 
                                                                                                                                                                    "Age.Group"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```